# How to generate a Shanghai QR Code for a foreign 3y old kid?

Tags: children, covid-19, shanghai

Due to the 2020 epidemic, museums in Shanghai are restricting access to kids who can show a green "Shanghai QR Code".

As a traveller, how do I get a "Shanghai QR Code" for my 3y old kid who is a foreigner (non-Chinese)?

For reference,

- I was able to get a Shanghai QR Code for myself from the application Alipay, but that app is restricted to people of age 4 and older with their own phone number and bank account number.
- Alipay lets you generate a Shanghai QR Code for other family members, but only if they have a Chinese name and Chinese ID.

Comment: In practice: foreign kids have been accepted entry with parents QR codes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because QR codes have now been abolished in China

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the Health Declaration Certificate system. Register and provide evidence of your negative PCR test [on this website](https://hrhk.cs.mfa.gov.cn/H5/). There is also the option to do this for others - no matter their age. After this has been reviewed, you will both receive a green QR code marked with "HDC".

[Source](http://gb.china-embassy.gov.cn/eng/visa/jiankangmaEn/202011/t20201125_10434625.htm).

Alternatively, if this is not accepted for domestic purposes, staff at the PCR test compounds can manually add children to the system if you bring the passport of the child.

Comment: Answering right after the whole country abandoned the QR code verification system. :P

Comment: @Cœur As of the 16th November 2022, [this still seems to be used](http://toronto.china-consulate.gov.cn/eng/zxdt/202211/t20221116_10976024.htm).

Comment: This was and is only for international travel and was not recognized for most domestic purposes.

Comment: The domestic QR codes were specific to each province or even city, and often contained more information than test results, but also e.g. position history and vaccination and quarantine status.

Comment: I'm referring to this news from a week ago: https://www.theregister.com/2022/12/13/china_bins_covid_app/

Comment: @xngtng Since the OP doesn't seem to have a spare phone number, from  what I see the other option is staff at PCR test compounds manually adding the child to the system (passport required). I have added this to my answer.

Comment: @Cœur Yes, this probably shouldn't have a bounty...